# PHP Apache script running as www-data unable to mkdir

Tags: permissions, apache2, php

I am rather new to Ubuntu and I am enjoying my server experience so far, but I am having an issue with creating a directory with php, despite the permissions being correct (as far as I am aware). I am running an Apache2 instance on Ubuntu 18.04, trying to run the following line of php:

```
mkdir($sharexdir, 0755, true);
```

When I do, I get a php warning with "Permissions denied" in this file, on that line. I have tried setting the php file permissions to 777, all sub-folders within this directory (which the php file should create a directory in) all have permissions of 755. The script is running as the user `www-data:www-data` as the per the chown `chown www-data:www-data /var/www/grounddug/cdn`

If anyone has any solutions, I would be very thankful, I have been trying to resolve this for quite a while now. Please let me know if I miss important information or comment if you need anything else, I just want to be as helpful as I can to get this isue solved.

Comment: To add on to this, I just ran `get_current_user()` and the reply was root, which should never have any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further inspection, folders within the domain did not have Group 33 assigned, which was needed for the php script to access.